# C# Sockets and sending data to all clients

Tags: c#, sockets

OK, so I am not very good at programming in general, but I want to try my hand at using sockets. To start I watched a Youtube video which I followed step by step, I got the finished product working 100% to the guides however I wish to modify it in order for the server to be able to send a message to all connected clients.

Here is the youtube video: [Youtube Video - Sockets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI)

So this is the code for the server class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        public static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        public static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server, " + clientSockets.Count.ToString() + " clients are connected";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public static void SetupServer()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            Console.Title = "Server, " + clientSockets.Count.ToString() + " clients are connected";
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallBack), socket);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] databuff = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, databuff, received);

            string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(databuff);
            Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + s);
            string response = string.Empty;
            if (s.ToLower() == "get time")
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            else
            {
                response = "Invalid Request";
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), socket);
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallBack), socket);
            }




        private static void sendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

I had a pretty pathetic attempt at what I wanted to do:

```
private static void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] databuff = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, databuff, received);

            string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(databuff);
            Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + s);
            foreach(Socket s1 in clientSockets){
            string response = string.Empty;
            if (s.ToLower() == "get time")
            {
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            else
            {
                response = "Invalid Request";
            }

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            s1.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), s1);
            s1.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallBack), s1);
            }
        }
```

wasn't really expecting it too work, but I gave it a go.

Another secondary question:

Is this the line of code which determines what IP and Port the server will be listening on?

```
_serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
```

Comment: UDP would likely be a better fit for the type of behavior you're looking for. TCP multicast is still a bit clunky from my experience.

Comment: LeftTechticle (the guy who made the video) is a buddy of mine and I sent him the link to this question. He might want to help you :)

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks for the suggestion I will definitely take it into consider once I actually get it working XD.

Comment: @ByteBlast Thank you very much, if he could take a look at it I would really appreciate it :D

Comment: Figured it out, Solved.

Comment: @SimonTaylor Glad you managed to solve it. Can you share your solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Used the same code, had the same problem.

It is not working because the client console is stuck in `readLine()`, so it is not receiving responses. After you send a command don't call `Console.ReadLine` again.

To loop trough all clients and send a message:

```
private static void sentToAll(string s)
{
    foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
    {                
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        socket.Send(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     private static IPEndPoint localEndPoint;
    public static String IpAddress = "10.0.0.13";
 public static int port = 3000;
    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress), port);
                _serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
```

Comment: Just posting a code snipped is usually not accepted. Can you elaborate with a words?